# Is it possible to zoom, when someone clicks on a link (image)?

Tags: javascript, html, css

On my main page, I have 3 links (images). Like a portal.

This is what i want to make:
When you click on one of the links, you zoom really far onto that one. So far that it filled up the full screen. But I dont want you to see whats in that page yet.

Example:
http://prezi.com/0ehjgvtr9fzu/?utm_campaign=share&utm_medium=copy (click on the cloud which says:"Main idea")

Is this possible with HTML/CSS/JavaScript?

Comment: That website uses Adobe flash...

Comment: "Is this possible with HTML/CSS/JavaScript?"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't "zoom" the viewport but you can use CSS/JS to mimic the behavior by scaling elements in animations. With CSS transforms/transitions you can pretty easily scale a "page" down and then expand it on click (like your demo Flash object).

Basic demo:

```
#container {
    transform-style : preserve-3d;
    perspective     : 400px;
}

#container .page {
    transition : transform 500ms ease-out;
    transform  : scale(0.2);
}

#container .page.make-page-big {
    transform : scale(1);
}
```

Where `#container` is the "viewport" and `.page` is a page that will be animated into full-view.

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/j1k3mcLp/

That should get you started, you can do a lot with 3D transforms as well, which will allow you to really get the effect you want.

**UPDATE**

Here's a demo using 3D transforms: http://jsfiddle.net/j1k3mcLp/1/

Comment: Could you fiddle this for me? Becuase i dont understand what you mean with .page.

Comment: @MrDikke I was working on one, it's part of the answer now. This should get you started but you probably want to look into 3D transforms because you can get really specific with the effects you create in three dimensional space. **UPDATE**: I added a 3D transforms demo.

Comment: is it also possible that "Click me" changes to an image, and when you zoom in you see an other background color which is the same as the image? If that makes any sense?

Comment: @MrDikke The possibilities are really only limited by your imagination. There are a lot of things that can be animated with `transition`s but for some more complex animations you may need to use CSS `animation`s. If you're not familiar with these, check-out the MDN documentation, there are really good examples and once you have the basics, there are a ton of examples/demos out there you can find on Google.

Comment: @MrDikke One last thing, if you are not aware, there is an awesome browser-feature-checking tool called http://caniuse.com. Be aware of browser restrictions with CSS `transform`s/`transition`s as they are only a part of modern browsers (although well supported in modern browsers now).